# How can I match a repeating pattern within a repeating pattern without specifying the alternatives twice?

Tags: regex, pcre

Suppose I have the following string, representing one or many days or day ranges:

```
mon,thu..fri,sun
```

How can I match any arbitrary list of ranges or single days with a regular expression, **without expanding the day alternatives twice**?

I currently have this:

```
(?P<weekdays>
    (                        
        \b
        (mon|tue|wed|thu|fri|sat|sun)
        (\.\.(mon|tue|wed|thu|fri|sat|sun))?
        ,?
    )*
)
```

... this works, but it forces me to repeat the day alternatives in the regex (which are simplified here but are longer!). Note that this regex matches for `fri,sat,` thus optionally ending in a comma, this IS the desired behavior.

I also tried making the range portion a limited repetition using `{1,2}`, but I am unable to avoid matching the invalid `mon..tue..fri` because the pattern restarts via the optional comma.

Note that this is part of a longer regex so I can't use the global flag.

[This is the Regex101 URL](https://regex101.com/r/8V2FG6/5), where I also added some unit tests.

**Small edit:** used the \b metacharacter instead of a negative lookahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PCRE named group and reuse a sub-pattern later using `(?&groupName)` construct:

```sh
^(?<weekdays>
    (                        
        \b
        (?<weeks>mon|tue|wed|thu|fri|sat|sun)
        (?:\.\.(?&weeks))?
        ,?
    )+
)$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8V2FG6/6)

---

To keep definition separate from reference, use `DEFINE` directive of PCRE:

```sh
(?(DEFINE)
   (?<weeks>mon|tue|wed|thu|fri|sat|sun)
)
^(?P<weekdays>
    (?:                        
        \b
        (?&weeks)
        (?:\.\.(?&weeks))?
        ,?
    )*
)$
```

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/8V2FG6/7)

Comment: Nice, I had no idea you could just reference whole patterns. Note that the original negative lookahead wasn't necessary, apparently `\b` does the trick (to avoid `tuetue`). On your added part, you also used `((?&weeks))`, I guess you mean just `(?&weeks)`

Comment: Indeed `(?&weeks)` is sufficient. I just mimicked your original regex that had 5 captured groups. I didn't attempt to clean/refactor regex. Will do it now

Comment: @ikegami: Incidentally, that was my originally posted answer with [demo link](https://regex101.com/r/8V2FG6/3) then I thought of reducing overall length :)

Comment: Both are useful! I am not sure why the question was flagged duplicate, the solution could be similar, but I am not necessarily asking about reusing patterns, and I imagine there are ways to do this without referencing the pattern. (btw, this answer is much better and complete than the one in the "original")

Comment: @istepaniuk: Yes agreed, linked answer is not really a dupe.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
/(\bmon\b|\btue\b|\bwed\b|\bthu\b|\bfri\b|\bsat\b|\bsun\b)/g
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you perhaps elaborate a bit more? Try that how? The boundary metacharacter could be an interesting thing to apply here, but I don't see how your regex relates to my question (despite being days)

Answer (score 0):

Note that you don't even need a reference to a capture group or a capture group at all for what you are trying to do. Playing with a word boundary suffices:

```
\A \b
(?:
    (?: , |  \.\. )?                
    (?: mon|tue|wed|thu|fri|sat|sun) \b
)++
\z
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/urlhEH/2)

Comment: Interesting, but this would match on "mon..tue..fri", right? You can run the unit tests (on the link you provided)

Comment: We can try this: ```^(?P<weekdays>    (?:    (?:,|(?<!\....)\.\.|^) 
    (?:mon|tue|wed|thu|fri|sat|sun)     )+     )$```